# Can't deploy from Github Subfolder to Azure Deployment Slot

Tags: linux, visual-studio, azure, github, azure-web-app-service

**Edit:**

Before reading everything below, I can be more succinct in asking why is Azure/KuduSync ignoring my `.deployment` file and how do I instruct the Kudu App Service to process the file?

I have written a Node.js/React project using Visual Studio 2017. When I link it to a GitHub repository, it copies the parent directory which contains the `.sln` file and the project folder containing the `node.js` application.

The problem I'm running into is when I deploy the repository to my Azure deployment slot, Kudu copies the root of the GitHub repository containing the `.sln` file and the subfolder to the wwwroot folder.

When I browse to the Azure website, I have to go to the

```
[name].azurewebsite.net/[subfoldername]
```

to access `Index.html`.

I have tried creating a `.deployment` file with the following configuration:

```
[config]
project=[subfolder]
```

I have placed this in the root of my GitHub repository.  When I try to deploy, KuduSync ignores the `.deployment` file.

I have also tried creating a "PROJECT" application setting pointing to the subdirectory and flagging it as a "Deployment slot setting" within my Azure web app slot.

None of these options have instructed Kudu to deploy directly from the subfolder rather than the root of the repository.

[Edit] This is the GitHub and Azure directory structure
[Snapshots of Directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lx5lo.jpg)

[Here's the log from Azure.  As you can see it ignores the .deployment file]

```
    Command: kudusync -v 50 -f /home/site/repository <br/>
-t /home/site/wwwroot <br/>
-n /home/site/deployments/[site]/manifest <br/>
-p /home/site/firstDeploymentManifest <br/>
**-i ".git;.hg;.deployment;.deploy.sh"** <br/>
Kudu sync from: '/home/site/repository' to: '/home/site/wwwroot' <br/>
**Ignoring: .deployment** <br/>
Copying file: '.gitattributes' <br/>
Copying file: '.gitignore' <br/>
```

Comment: So you want to make the default interface of the deployment project index.html? What is the path of your index.html file in your project?

Comment: Which kind of OS your App Service Instance on? Linux or Windows?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.  So I deployed a Linux container in Azure.  I am using Windows OS.  So the structure of the repository is:  *Root - [Application].sln **[Sub Directory] - Index.html, Server.js, package.json, [folders], [other files]

Comment: can you show the index code of Server.js?

Comment: You don't have index.html in the root directory of your project, so you need to use [name].azurewebsite.net/[subfoldername] to access index.html. For App Service working on Linux, you can select to use the .js file to modify the path of default page.

Comment: Hi Bowman, I understand that the index is not in the root.  The thing is I am trying to force Azure Deployment service to copy the contents of the subdirectory rather than copy the root of the repository.  Also, when I move the contents of the sub directory up to wwwroot, the website works fine.  But I don't want to do it manually as the .deployment file should tell Azure to retrieve the contents of the subdirectory.

Comment: I didn't use continuous deployment but when I tried to deploy the project to a Linux-based App Service, the deployment failed. The project was not deployed to the Azure App Service from the subfolders specified in the .deployment file. But deploying to a Windows-based App Service will not cause any problems. Regarding what caused this problem, I am still looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that using the Continuous Deployment option in Azure prevents me from using a custom deployment file.  Instead, I decided to create another repository in GitHub from my subfolder.  This will allow me to us Azure CD/CI to write my project files directly to wwwroot.  Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: Hi, if you solve this problem, you can mark your solution as the answer of your question. This will help others solve similar questions.